# MS Excel - VBA - Issues with searching a #, then returning relevant cells to different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a workbook in Excel that I can add orders at my work and it stores into a database. I have another sheet that you can type in an order number (ECO number in the code) and I want it to display the # plus any relevant part numbers. I am having issue getting it to select only the range that I need.

Here is what I have in VBA so far:

```
Sub PlayMacro()

  Dim Prompt As String
  Dim RetValue As String
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim RowCrnt As Long

  Prompt = ""

   With Sheets("ECO Database")

    Do While True
      RetValue = InputBox(Prompt & "Type in ECO#")
      
      If RetValue = "" Then
        Exit Do
      End If


      Set Rng = .Columns("A:A").Find(What:=RetValue, After:=.Range("A1"), _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

      If Rng Is Nothing Then
       Prompt = "ECO""" & RetValue & """Not Found"
      Else
        
        
        
            Sheets("ECO Updates").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:T49").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Sheets("ECO Database").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Range("A1").Select
  
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveCell.Range("A:U").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ECO Updates").Select
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
        
        
        
        
      End If
      Prompt = Prompt & vbLf
    Loop

  End With

End Sub
```

I have gotten it to pop up with a dialog box and ask for the number I want. I type it in, and I get errors due to my programming mistakes, or it selects everything in the sheet (All cells) and memory issues arise. I used the macro recorder so you can see that I'm very much a novice.

I have in column A the ECO number that I'm searching for. In Columns B through U I have the data I want. When I add the ECO orders into the database, I've left one blank row between all of them. I thought it would be easier to find where they end, but obviously I'm  having difficulty. The reason I want to copy/eventually cut the data is so that any ECO can be adjusted and then "Saved" (Copy/Cut back to the database). Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated!

*PS* I'm not allowed to add images yet it says, otherwise I would show you what the format is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got as a solution after more time working on this! I have updated my entire sheet with some extras also. This achieves the result I want! Now I'm just struggling getting it to display a msg box with an error rather than a compiling error when I search for something that isn't found. You'll have to ignore the comments behind the ' as that is me trying to get this damn thing to say Not Found. It is coming up with that message when I search for something that DOES exist. A different problem for a different day.

```
Sub ECO_SEARCH()


Dim val As String
'Dim Rng As Range

'Is B1 empty?
    If IsEmpty(Range("B1").value) = True Then
        MsgBox "Please enter an ECO#"
        Range("A3:T150").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        GoTo LastLine
    End If


    Sheets("ECO Updates").Select
    Range("A3:T150").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-21
    Range("B1").Select
    val = Range("B1").value
    'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "B1"""
    Sheets("ECO Database").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    
    
    Cells.Find(What:=val, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase _
    :=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    'If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    '    MsgBox "ECO# Not Found!"
    '    GoTo LastLine
    'End If
        
    
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 18)).Select
             
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("ECO Updates").Select
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A3:T150").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range("A3:T150").Font.Size = 10
    Range("A3:T150").Font.Bold = False
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThin
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinous
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinous
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = vbBlack
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = vbBlack
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = vbBlack
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlEdgeRight).Color = vbBlack
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Color = vbBlack
    Range("A3:T150").Borders(xlInsideVertical).Color = vbBlack
    Range("A3:T150").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range("A3:T150").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    
    
    
LastLine:
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to edit the code to show properly? How do I do this?

Comment: I figured out the issue with the "Not Found" coming up by using a Do While loop. That wasn't part of this thread, but there it is! Thanks for reading.